# How to populate an array in Vue with data from Axios request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

v-breadcrumbs displays data from the breadcrumbs array - this works fine with static data.

```
<v-row>
    <!-- Breadcrumbs -->
    <v-col class="d-flex">
        <v-breadcrumbs :items="breadcrumbs"></v-breadcrumbs>
    </v-col>
</v-row>

<v-row>
    <v-col class="d-flex">
        <p class="blue--text title font-weight-medium my-0">{{response.products.title}}</p>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Axios makes a get request to get various data about a product - this also works fine.

```
<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({$axios, params}){
    try{
      let response = await $axios.$get(`/api/products/${params.id}`)
      console.log(responce);

      return{
        responce: responce
      }
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    breadcrumbs: [{text: "Category", href: "index"}, {text: "", disabled: true}]
  })
</script>
```

I would then like to use the data returned from the get request to propagate the last item in the breadcrumb array.

I tried using a promise to insert the value after the get request has complete but in doing so the whole app crashes with **" Cannot read property 'products' of undefined "** regardless of what code is executed in the promise.

```
let response = await $axios.$get(`/api/products/${params.id}`)
                     .then((result) => {
                       // Some code here
                     })
```

I realise I must be altering the 'response' value somehow in using the .then() promise. Is this the best way to solve this problem or should I be looking into Vue lifecycle hooks?

Here is the API response to the get request:

```
{
  success: true,
  products: {
    rating: [],
    _id: '5e3bfd038125ebafba2ff8ce',
    owner: {
      _id: '5e397eed2da03d0817f3f870',
      name: 'Jeff Bezos',
      about: 'Jeff is the owner of this site.',
      photo: '-',
      __v: 0
    },
    category: { _id: '5e397bcc2da03d0817f3f86d', type: 'Books', __v: 0 },
    title: 'The Everything Store',
    description: 'A book about Amazon',
    photo: '-',
    price: 12,
    stockQuantity: 73,
    __v: 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a variable to affect your DOM you have to declare it as a property in the data function of the Vue isntance:

```
data: () => ({
  breadcrumbs: [{text: "Category", href: "index"}, {text: "", disabled: true}],
  response: null
})
```

Then, in order to access the `response` data property, you have to use a lifecycle hook. For example:

```
<script>
// import axios if needed

export default {
  data: () => ({
    breadcrumbs: [{text: "Category", href: "index"}, {text: "", disabled: true}]
  }),
  created(){
      // I don't know where params object comes form
      $axios.$get(`/api/products/${params.id}`)
      .then(response => {
        this.response = response;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  },

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script define `response`, it will be then known by your Vue component :

```
data: () => ({
  breadcrumbs: [{text: "Category", href: "index"}, {text: "", disabled: true}],
  response: {}
})
```

then, affect it in the `then` of axios call, it's how it work :

```
$axios.$get(`/api/products/${params.id}`)
                 .then((result) => {
                   this.response = result
                 })
```